# Need help C# id manager not working when run asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have written a id manager for a xml repository. The repository manages entries in the xml file and assigns unique id (integers) to each entry that is added. The same way databases auto assign new id's to entries added to a table.

The repository will be called asynchronously so I need the id manager to be thread safe. I am using the C# lock statement but it does not seem to help. My unit tests succeed in single threaded execution but fail when run in parallel ( IE: Task ). Specifically they only fail with large sets of parallel tasks above 1000+ and even only then they only fail every other time.

The exception states that it expected 10000 but got 9998. The exception is always the same having to do with 2 missing id that were not registered.

What the heck am I missing?

ID Manager code and unit tests are provided below. The id manager utilizes Linq and is thus not very performance oriented with large sets of id's. Unit Tests TestAsyncRegistration and TestAsyncRandomRegistration are the tests that throw the exceptions.

```
public class IdManager
{
    private List<int> idList = new List<int>();
    private List<int> availableList = new List<int>();

    private int nextId;

    private int bufferCount;
    object obj = new object();

    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> RegisteredIds
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(this.idList);
        }
    }

    public int BufferCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bufferCount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
            }

            this.bufferCount = value;
        }
    }

    public IdManager(int bufferCount)
    {
        this.BufferCount = bufferCount;
        this.Reset();
    }

    public IdManager()
        : this(1000)
    {
    }

    public void RegisterId(int id)
    {
        this.RegisterId(new[] { id });
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        lock (this.obj)
        {
            this.availableList.Clear();
            this.idList.Clear();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.bufferCount; i++)
            {
                this.availableList.Add(i);
            } 
        }
    }

    public void RegisterId(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        lock (this.obj)
        {
            var distinct = ids.Except(this.idList);
            this.idList.AddRange(distinct);
            this.availableList = this.availableList.Except(this.idList).ToList(); 
        }
    }

    public int NewId()
    {
        lock (this.obj)
        {
            if (this.availableList.Count > 0)
            {
                var item = this.availableList[0];
                this.availableList.RemoveAt(0);
                this.idList.Add(item);
                return item;
            }

            var max = this.idList.Max();

            for (var i = 1; i < this.bufferCount; i++)
            {
                this.availableList.Add(max + i);
            }

            this.availableList = this.availableList.Except(this.idList).ToList();

            return this.NewId(); 
        }
    }
}
```

... and the unit test code ...

```
[TestClass]
public class IdManagerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSequence()
    {
        var manager = new IdManager(5);
        for (var i = 0; i < manager.BufferCount + 10; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(i, manager.NewId());
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBrokenSequence()
    {
        var manager = new IdManager(5);
        manager.RegisterId(1);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, manager.NewId());
        Assert.AreEqual(2, manager.NewId());
        for (var i = 3; i < manager.BufferCount + 10; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(i, manager.NewId());
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestForwardSequence()
    {
        var manager = new IdManager(5);
        manager.RegisterId(0);
        manager.RegisterId(1);
        manager.RegisterId(2);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, manager.NewId());
        Assert.AreEqual(4, manager.NewId());
        for (var i = 5; i < manager.BufferCount + 10; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(i, manager.NewId());
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBackwardSequence()
    {
        var manager = new IdManager(5);
        manager.RegisterId(2);
        manager.RegisterId(1);
        manager.RegisterId(0);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, manager.NewId());
        Assert.AreEqual(4, manager.NewId());
        for (var i = 5; i < manager.BufferCount + 10; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(i, manager.NewId());
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestLargeNumbersRegistration()
    {
        // register a list of id's from 0 to 1000
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        var manager = new IdManager(1000);
        manager.RegisterId(list);

        var taskCount = 10000;
        var taskList = new Task[taskCount];
        var idValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Length; i++)
        {
            manager.RegisterId(idValue++);
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(taskCount, manager.NewId());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestAsyncRegistration()
    {
        // register a list of id's from 0 to 1000
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        var manager = new IdManager(1000);
        manager.RegisterId(list);

        var taskCount = 10000;
        var taskList = new Task[taskCount];
        var idValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Length; i++)
        {
            taskList[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => manager.RegisterId(idValue++));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskList);

        Assert.AreEqual(taskCount, manager.NewId());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestAsyncRandomRegistration()
    {
        // register a list of id's from 0 to 1000
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        // randomize the order of the id's in the list
        var random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        var randomizedList = from item in list
                             orderby random.Next()
                             select item;

        var manager = new IdManager(1000);
        manager.RegisterId(randomizedList);

        var taskCount = 10000;
        var taskList = new Task[taskCount];
        var idValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Length; i++)
        {
            taskList[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => manager.RegisterId(idValue++));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskList);

        Assert.AreEqual(taskCount, manager.NewId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your test, not the method that you're testing, specifically the snippet:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => manager.RegisterId(idValue++));
```

You're calling `idValue++` from a bunch of different threads simultaneously.  That's not a safe operation to perform.  Either increment `idValue` outside of `StartNew` and pass in the already incremented value, or use `Interlocked.Increment` to handle it safely.